# Can't access instance created in main in any other class

Tags: c#

UPDATE 2:
i can not access any instance i make in main method in other classes! simple as that! even when i make everything public! i dono why its like this...

UPDATE 3:
now i just have one question now if u willing to answer make 2 classes and make an instance of each on the main() and use INSTANCE of one of them in anothers body. can u do that pls and i make new project and see if this works. if it didnt its my pc!

What am I missing?

MY OLD QUESTION:
I tried 2 ways still can't access form instances in C#:

1. I instantiate a Telerik form in Main body but i can not access it from another forms button click event.
2. I also tried to add all forms into a single class as members and instantiate the class to access its forms but still cant access the class in a forms click event.

Comment: Where is the code for that class? We need to see it to help you

Comment: sure @CodingYoshi

Comment: You'll need to new up FormInstances in the handler to access it's public members, but I'm not sure that's what you want to do, we need more context.

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes what about it?

Comment: `FormInstances f = new FormInstances(); var frm = f.OLoginFrm;` you are saying that doesn't work?

Comment: i just updated the question @CodingYoshi

Comment: So the above code I wrote doesn't work?

Comment: no! something is very wrong with me or my pc @CodingYoshi

Comment: Can you paste your entire code on pastebin and i will take a look

Comment: now i just have one question now if u willing to answer make 2 classes and make an instance of each on the main() and use INSTANCE of one of them in anothers body. can u do that pls and i make new project and see if this works. if it didnt its my pc!

Comment: @CodingYoshi I updated the question check it out pls.

Comment: If you want me to help you then put your code on pastebin.

Comment: sure where is paste bin? @CodingYoshi

Comment: http://pastebin.com and it will give you a link so you can share the link with me

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pupEkxwF here it is

Comment: @CodingYoshi thank u

Comment: we can do teamviewe(remot desktop) if u want @CodingYoshi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132027/discussion-between-codingyoshi-and-thedeparted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have, say 2 forms then here is how to share something between them:

```
public class Shareable
{

}

public class Form1
{
    public Shareable Shareable { get; set; }
}

public class Form2
{
    public Form2()
    {
        // Now in this clas you can access the item to be shared
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        var sharedItem = frm.Shareable;
    }
}
```